# Error: (38, 12) Error: Can not find symbol Symbol: Methods getMapAsync (LocationActivity)

Tags: android, google-maps

sorry my English is pool,this is code:

```
public class LocationActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        SupportMapFragment map =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

this is xml:

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

this is gradle:

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
```

this is Manifast:

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="APK"/>
```

Error:

```
Error: (39, 12) Error: Can not find symbol,
Symbol: Methods getMapAsync (LocationActivity),
Location: SupportMapFragment type of variable map,
NOTE: Some input files use or cover the deprecated API.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; seethe compiler error output for details.
```

My project compile other rely, is this error? if I new project and write the same code like this ,this is no error, I try many ways and find many website but not solve ,I need help and want you can show the code Thank you!

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="android_key" />
Add this in Manifest and try

Comment: What happens if you use com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2?